# Python futurize without replacing / with old_div

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am using [futurize --stage2](http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html#stage-2-py3-style-code-with-wrappers-for-py2) which aplies a number of source-source transformation to make the code python2 and python3 compatible. One of those fixes is that all divisions `a/b` are replaced by `old_div(a/b)`, which I would like to avoid (there is too many, and many of them are replaced unnecessarily, such as `math.pi/2.`. The documentation says that `--nofix` (or `-x`) can be used to avoid running a certain fixes, but trying `--nofix=fix_divison` or `--nofix=libfuturize.fixes.fix_divison` has no effect with `--stage2`. Can someone perhaps help how to ignore that particular fixer otherwise?

Comment: you could add `from __future__ import division` and make sure that all integer divisions use `//`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that's what I will do. I only wanted to avoid having the code littered with `old_div` after futurize runs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Omit the prefix `fix_`.

```
futurize --nofix=division ...
```

Depending on version you're using, you may need to specify the `division_safe`:

```
futurize --nofix=division_safe ...
```

Comment: `division_safe` did it. Thx!